# List of vectors with entries aligned

Tags: align

**I am trying to produce a list of vectors formatted as follows.**

```
            a = (   1,   1,  25,   1,   5)               (1)
            b = (  50,   k,   1,   k,  80)               (2)
            c = (   0,  35, 1+k, 200,   1)               (3)
```

The important features are:

- The **commas are lined up**, and each vector entry is right aligned, so it is easy to compare `a[3]` with `b[3]` and `c[3]`.
- The vector entries may be numbers or symbols, so they need to be in **math mode**.
- Each vector has an **equation number** on the right, continuous with the numbers generated by `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}` environments from amsmath.
- The **overall block is centered** on the page.

What I have tried:

```latex
\begin{align}
 a &= (  1, & 1, & 25, & 1, & 5) \\
 % ...
\end{align}
```

This produces strange alignment (as does `flalign`).

```latex
\begin{align}
\begin{matrix}
 a &= &( & 1, & 1, & 25, & 1, & 5 & ) \\
 % ...
\end{matrix}
\end{align}
```

This produces more-or-less correct alignment (the commas don't line up, but the parentheses do), but no equation numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done with `alignat`, which is similar to `align` except there is no space between the columns. I added a `\`  space but you could use `\,` or `\quad` or any other space. The columns alternate left-right alignment, so to get consecutive right-aligned columns, use `&&`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{6}
 a = (\ &&   1,\ &&  1,\ && 25,\ &&  1,\ &&  5\ ) \\
 b = (\ &&  50,\ &&  k,\ &&  1,\ &&  k,\ && 80\ ) \\
 c = (\ &&   0,\ && 35,\ && 1+k,\ && 200,\ &&  1\ )
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`IEEEtrantools`](https://moser-isi.ethz.ch/docs/typeset_equations.pdf)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{
  r % name
  C % equals
  .r % (
  .r.r.r.r.r % entries
  .r % )
}
a &= ( &  1, &  1, &  25, &   1, &  5 & ) \\
b &= ( & 50, &  k, &   1, &   k, & 80 & ) \\
c &= ( &  0, & 35, & 1+k, & 200, &  1 & )
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, such input is a nuisance, if you have several of these instances.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{vectorarray}{mb}
 {
  \max_vectorarray:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
 {}

\seq_new:N \l__max_vectorarray_items_seq
\seq_new:N \l__max_vectorarray_rows_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \max_vectorarray:nn
 {
  % #1 is the number of components
  % #2 is a list of items of the form {a}{1,2,3,4} separated by \\
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__max_vectorarray_items_seq { \\ } { #2 }
  \seq_clear:N \l__max_vectorarrat_rows_seq
  \seq_map_function:NN \l__max_vectorarray_items_seq \__max_vectorarray_item:n
  \exp_args:Nne \begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rC .r \prg_replicate:nn{#1}{.r} .r}
  \seq_use:Nn \l__max_vectorarray_rows_seq { \\ }
  \end{IEEEeqnarray}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__max_vectorarray_item:n
 {
  \__max_vectorarray_item_aux:nn #1
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__max_vectorarray_item_aux:nn
 {
  \seq_put_right:Nx \l__max_vectorarray_rows_seq
   {
    #1 & = & ( & \clist_use:nn { #2 } { , & } & )
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{
  r % name
  C % equals
  .r % (
  .r.r.r.r.r % entries
  .r % )
}
a &= ( &  1, &  1, &  25, &   1, &  5 & ) \\
b &= ( & 50, &  k, &   1, &   k, & 80 & ) \\
c &= ( &  0, & 35, & 1+k, & 200, &  1 & )
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\begin{vectorarray}{5}
{a}{1,1,25,1,5} \\
{b}{50,k,1,k,80} \\
{c}{0,35,1+k,200,1}
\end{vectorarray}


\end{document}
```

It would be possible to avoid having to specify the number of vector components.

[image]